# Is there a way out to get the logs from cloudwatch into graylog?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, graylog, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

How do we send logs from cloudwatch into graylog.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [AWS Plugin For Graylog](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog-plugin-aws)